# Spring 3.1, JSON response ModelAndView

Tags: java, json, spring, response, partial-views

This is my first post. I'm sorry for my english...

I have problem with postJSON and returning partial view with ModelAndView.

My controller:

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUrl.html")
public @ResponseBody ModelAndView addSubMenu(@RequestBody Menu menu) {
    ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView(PathConfig.MENU_DIR + "show_url");

    int id = menuService.saveOrUpdateMenu(1, menu.getTitle(), menu.getUrl(), 4, "pl");
    mav.addObject("submenu", menuService.get(id));
    return mav;
}
```

My ajax code:

```
$("#menuUrl").submit(function(){
    var menu = $(this).serializeObject();

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: config.resourcePath+"/addUrl.html",
        data: JSON.stringify(menu),
        dataType: 'json',
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        success: function(response){
            $( "#site" ).append(response);
        },
        error: function(e){
            alert("Server did not response.");
        }
    });

});
```

But... I have error: Server did not response...

How I can render partial view with json?

Thanks.

Comment: Do you have a JSON serializer on the *classpath* like Jackson and the `@RequestMapping` annotation has the correct value of URL - `/addUrl.html`?

Comment: I am confused. Do you want to return rendered HTML or a JSON Datamodel? Your server would like to serialize the ModelAndView Object as a JSON string and your jQuery code wants to append an HTML element to the DOM.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$("#menuUrl").submit(function(){
    var obj = $(this).serializeObject();
    obj.parentId = getParentId(menuDivId);

    $.ajax({
        url: config.resourcePath+"/addUrl.html", 
        data : JSON.stringify(obj),
        contentType : 'application/json',
        type : 'POST',
        context: document.body,
    }).done(function(response) {
        $("#site").append(response);
    });

    return false;
});
```

And controller returning ModelAndView. 
It's working.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few things which could be wrong here:

By specifying a `Content-type` header of `application/json` you are expecting a response of json back, however looking at the way you are handling the response it looks like what you want is an html

if it is html that you are looking for as a response then remove the Content-Type header from the request, remove the `@ResponseBody` annotation from `ModelAndView` response , instead just return a view which points to a normal jsp which can create the html response that you are expecting..

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUrl.html")
public ModelAndView addSubMenu(@RequestBody Menu menu) {
...
}
```

Comment: This would deliver HTML Code (Model delivered form controller, view delivered from Template) to the client. This would be my understanding of a partial. Then you would need to tell JQuery to expect HTML or Text but not JSON.

Answer (score 0):

If what you want is json to update some parts of the page don't return a ModelAndView, return String, make sure to have a json serializer

```
    @RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.POST, value = "/addUrl.html")
    public @ResponseBody String addSubMenu() {
         //yourvariable
         return yourvariable.toString();
    }
```

Comment: This would deliver what ever you have in yourvariable. If you want to return an object, consider returning an Object and let Spring marshal it to JSON. If you want to deliver some browser renderable code, I would delegate the view rendering to the View layer using ModelAndView (without the ReponseBody Annotation) as result

Comment: True, it will return a String, if an object is needed, replace String with your object and you can serialize it using jackson library for example.